# Delete or Filter object based on Boolean values using raw JavaScript or underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a JavaScript object which contains 2 objects with different true/false Boolean and wanted to filter out the first object as it has all false values.

If in any scenario, any key is true then it should retain, and shouldn't filter out the data object.

I wanted to keep the 2nd object only based on any true value, as you can see it has some 'true' values.

Let me explain it further, as you could see the first object of 'data' which has all the Boolean values as 'false' should be omitted and end result should have the 2nd data object only as it's some 'true' values.

```
"data": [{
                                "Products": "Mobile",
                                "Australia": false,
                                "Austria": false,
                                "Belgium": false,
                                "Canada": false,
                                "China": false,
                                "India": false,
                                "Poland": false,
                                "Brazil": false,
                                "US": false
                            }, 
                            {
                                "Products": "Tablet",
                                "Australia": false,
                                "Austria": true,
                                "Belgium": false,
                                "Canada": false,
                                "China": false,
                                "India": true,
                                "Poland": false,
                                "Brazil": true,
                                "US": false
                            }]
```

End result should be like this only, it should filter the first object because of all false values.

```
"data": [{
                                "Products": "Tablet",
                                "Australia": false,
                                "Austria": true,
                                "Belgium": false,
                                "Canada": false,
                                "China": false,
                                "India": true,
                                "Poland": false,
                                "Brazil": true,
                                "US": false
                            }]
```

Any suggestion using raw JavaScript or Underscore.js is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` and `some`.

```
data.filter(                             // Filter the data array by
  function(product) {                    // looking at each product in it
    return Object.keys(product)          // and for that product's keys
      .some(                             // see if any of the 
        function(key) {                  // keys
          return product[key] === true;  // have a value of true
        }
      )
    ;
  }
)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @torazaburo and +1 for comments with the code :)

I like the native methods over custom ones, anyways we only supporting latest browsers so there wouldn't be any need to polyfills or shims for legacy browsers.

Answer (score 1):

A version using underscore:

```
    var result = _.filter(data, function(product){
        return _.some(product, function(value){
            return _.isBoolean(value) && value;
        });
    });
```